# Modal UIViewController from middle of the screen

Tags: ios, swift, transition, modalviewcontroller

I have a transparent custom navigation bar like the one on this picture:

[image]

I would like to have a modal view that appears from just under the navigation bar up to half of the screen and make it feels like the navigation bar is expending until half of the screen. And I would like to animate it like if it is sliding down. It will just contain a UILabel, and it will appear when I click on the "i" information button on the top right corner.

I don't know how to make a translucent modal view appears from the middle of the screen instead of from a border. Especially since my navigation bar is transparent and my modal view should not appears behind it while appearing. Do you have any example or tutorial to help me do that?

I am coding in Swift :)

Comment: I think default navigation not used for this design so its better way use custom navigation for this design and hide default navigation.

Comment: It really doesn't seem like a `UIModalViewController` is what you're looking for here. I would suggest simply animating a view down with your `UILabel` on it instead of trying to instantiate an entirely new viewController that covers only half of the screen.